# Is there a way to style dialog alert in nativescript?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I am working on app in nativescript vue.js ad I'm having an alert box which **I want to style the 'massage' propety** for example to change the text color.

How can I do that?

here is  code snippet

```
alert({
                         message: "alerts saeved",
                         okButtonText: "close"
                    });
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of message by setting a color to Label in your CSS in your component

```
Label {
  color: red; // this color should be applied to message in dialog
}
```

Comment: It 's  not a label...
and anyway it will efect all labels, I want to target the specific massage

Comment: As I said already, the message takes styles of Label in your page. You can prevent other labels being affected by assigning a seperate style.

Comment: I tried adding what you said but it efekted the modal in page but not the alert,

Comment: It works on my end with alerts, if you have issues please share a Playground sample. Also confirm which device you are using for testing.